# Drawing straight lines on a tkinter canvas with Grid on python with mouse

Tags: canvas, tkinter, python-3.4

so currently I am working on a program that will allow origami artists to create crease patterns on their computer using this program. So far I have a program that draws a grid on the canvas and allows the user to draw a freeform line  , however, I require the user to able to draw straight lines but I'm unsure on how to adapt this code so the user can draws straight lines not freeform squiggle. Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

Mouse = "up"
xold, yold = None, None
def DrawGrid(drawing_area, line_distance):

   for x in range(line_distance,600,line_distance):
       drawing_area.create_line(x, 0, x, 600, fill="#d3d3d3")

   for y in range(line_distance,600,line_distance):
       drawing_area.create_line(0, y, 600, y, fill="#d3d3d3")

def main():
    root = Tk()
    drawing_area = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, bg='white')
    drawing_area.pack()
    DrawGrid(drawing_area, 10)
    drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", motion)
    drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", Mousedown)
    drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", Mouseup)

    root.mainloop()

def Mousedown(event):
    global Mouse
    Mouse = "down"         

def Mouseup(event):
    global Mouse, xold, yold
    Mouse = "up"
    xold = None           
    yold = None

def motion(event):
    if Mouse == "down":
        global xold, yold

    if xold is not None and yold is not None:
        event.widget.create_line(xold,yold,event.x,event.y,smooth=TRUE)

    xold = event.x
    yold = event.y


main()
```

Thank you, 
          Mistry27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to only let the user draw one line at a time. That is, as the mouse moves you don't keep creating new lines. Instead, modify the existing line.

For example, you could make it so that when the user clicks and then moves the mouse, no matter where the mouse is, only a single line is drawn from where they clicked to the current position. That will force the line to always be as straight as possible.

I started with your code and made as few changes as possible to show how this might work. If you click, drag, click, drag, click, etc, it will draw only one line segment between each click. If you want to start a new line completely disconnected from the current line, press the <kbd>escape</kbd> key.

In the code, the variable `current` contains the id of the line currently being drawn. When you press <kbd>escape</kbd>, this is reset to `None`. Whenever you click the mouse, a new line is started either from the end of `current` or the current mouse position. During a motion, we merely reset the endpoint of the current line.

```
from tkinter import *

current = None

def DrawGrid(drawing_area, line_distance):

   for x in range(line_distance,600,line_distance):
       drawing_area.create_line(x, 0, x, 600, fill="#d3d3d3")

   for y in range(line_distance,600,line_distance):
       drawing_area.create_line(0, y, 600, y, fill="#d3d3d3")

def main():
    root = Tk()
    drawing_area = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, bg='white')
    drawing_area.pack()
    DrawGrid(drawing_area, 10)
    drawing_area.bind("<Escape>", reset)
    drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", motion)
    drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", Mousedown)

    root.mainloop()

def reset(event):
    global current
    current = None

def Mousedown(event):
    global current

    event.widget.focus_set()  # so escape key will work

    if current is None:
        # the new line starts where the user clicked
        x0 = event.x
        y0 = event.y

    else:
        # the new line starts at the end of the previously
        # drawn line
        coords = event.widget.coords(current)
        x0 = coords[2]
        y0 = coords[3]

    # create the new line
    current = event.widget.create_line(x0, y0, event.x, event.y)

def motion(event):
    if current:
        # modify the current line by changing the end coordinates
        # to be the current mouse position
        coords = event.widget.coords(current)
        coords[2] = event.x
        coords[3] = event.y

        event.widget.coords(current, *coords)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, for my program I need the line to be drawn after the user un-clicks and not have the option of continuing the line from the end of the previous but I should be able to figure this out using your example.